# Absolute-ish secure access for private website

Tags: ssh, ssl-certificate, mediawiki, intranet

I planning to run a private media wiki server on debian(SELinux) for all my important home documents.

I would like to be able to securely access it from the outside with laptop, tablet, or even a live-CD like LPS.  It seems to me I would have the smallest attack surface if I only provided SSH to the cloud and tunneled in, maybe even incorporate a port knock to prevent casual detection. I will be serving content to a known and essentially unchanging set of users.  Bandwidth efficiency isn't really a factor as concurrent connections would be rare.

**Is there a more secure way to access a web server?** It seems the government really likes to use smart cards although I'm not sure how.  What about client side browser certificates? Yubikey?

Answer (score 1):

The safest solution is probably using a virtual private network so that the server cannot be contacted at all except through an SSH-like protocol. A decent router should support this; you can get more help over at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).